# How can I validate a XML-Schema?

Tags: python, xml, xsd, python-xmlschema

I don't have a lot of experience working with XML Schema definitions. I am working with a definition that consists of several XSD files and that is provided by a third party.

Now I've come to a point where I want to make sure that the XSD files are free of errors. So my question is whether how one can check an XML schema definition for errors.

I work with the Python library "xmlschema". The schema could be read in with `xmlschema.XMLSchema (filename)` without any problems. Is that already a clear indicator that the definition is free of errors? Furthermore, I ask myself whether the error-free reading not only means that the definition is syntactically correct, but there could still be logical errors.

Comment: no, I don't want to validate xml against an xml-schema, I want to validate the ""schema"".

Comment: I don't know the specific schema processor that Python uses, but yes, in general, you would expect that a library that has an operation to load/compile an XSD schema will perform full validation on that schema. Try it out on some schemas containing errors if you're not confident it will catch them.

Answer (score 1):

If you run `xmlschema.XMLSchema(filename)` the default validation mode is `strict`. This would cause to show an error message when the XSD file is not correct. I tested to change a name of a type, that is used in another element. This raises an exception on load.

Without Error
[image]

With Error (machineIdType renamed to machineIdTyp)
[image]